# How to detect if "&t_Co" is "defined" in my .vimrc?

Tags: terminal, vim

When I `:echo &t_Co` in my Vim, it shows my terminal colors. If I `:echo &t_Co` in my gVim, nothing is showed (since I'm not in terminal).

I would like to use a condition in my vimrc to detect this situation (the &t_Co with no value in gVim, how do I test it? I know I can use has("gui_running") to see if I'm in gVim or not, but I would like to know how to test a variable like &t_Co that isn't showing nothing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if !empty(&t_Co)
    " t_Co is set to a non-empty value
endif
```

(`exists('&t_Co')` doesn't help because it does exist in GVim, it's just empty.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. One more question: is it possible to know the maxinum number of colors a terminal can have in a condition?

Comment: `:set t_Co=` takes any integer, but XTerm can only display 256 (or 16, depending on configuration) colors.

Comment: Is there a function that I can run and detect the maximum colors a terminal can have? This would be interesting since I'm trying to create a vimrc being used in mac terminal, linux terminal, gvim, etc.